# Вопрос по handler

Tags: android, java

Подскажите, этот код будет все еще исполняться даже, если приложение android будет свернуто?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           textview.setText(calc()[0]);
           if (calc()[1]!=null){
               textview22.setTextSize(50);
            textview22.setText(calc()[1]);}

            handler.postDelayed(this, 500);
        }
    }, 500);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Да. Будет до тех пор, пока телефон не уснет. А засыпание может длиться часами.

Comment: Подскажи как этот удалить этот Runnable. Чтобы удалить из очереди Runnable ему сначала имя надо присвоить и потом removeCallbacks(имя)?